# Primefaces - La variable no se actualiza

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tengo la siguiente tabla dentro de un dialogo con un `p:commandLink`, que cuando se hace click se debe actualizar el valor de la variable `encab_idadmision`, tomado de `admv.idadmision`.

Ya revise y `admv.idadmision` tiene el valor, sin embargo `encab_idadmision`, no se actualiza.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
  <p:dataTable id="dt_buscar_adm" var="admv" value="#{b_ventas.l_bus_adm_tbl}" paginator="true" rows="10" styleClass="paginated">

                        <p:column style="width: 30px">
                              <p:commandLink update="fventas:head_nro_atencion" oncomplete="PF('pac_admitidos').hide();" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="float:left;margin-right:10px" title="View">
                                  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{admv.idadmision}" target="#{b_ventas.encab_idadmision}" />
                              </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>
```

Comment: Nunca utilices guiones o subguiones en las propiedades de una clase. En Java se utiliza fuertemente las nomenclaturas estandarizadas. Jamás una propiedad de una entidad o bean debe tener esos caracteres. Te recomiendo refactorizar el código.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta sintaxis

```
<p:commandLink update=":#{p:component('encab_idadmision')}"
```

Comment: Puedes explicar tu respuesta, por favor.

Comment: Estas tratando de actualizar un componente que esta fuera del alcance del command link , por lo tanto tienes que usar la expresión de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

Yo intentaría algo diferente, pero de todas formas si fuera tu lo haría en el listener del **commandLink** ya que no me gusta usar el **f:setPropertyActionListener** porque enmascara lógica en el **xhtml**

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="float:left;margin-right:10px" title="View">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{admv.idadmision}" target="#{b_ventas.encab_idadmision}" />
<p:ajax update="fventas:head_nro_atencion" oncomplete="PF('pac_admitidos').hide();" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que `fventas`es un `form`, y lo que te está pasando es que estás haciendo mal la referencia.

`<p:commandLink update="fventas:head_nro_atencion"...`

La referencia correcta debe ser con dos puntos antes, de la siguiente manera:

`<p:commandLink update="`***:fventas:head_nro_atencion***"... `

Normalmente cuando algún elemento no se está referenciando correctamente, no se ejecutan ciertas acciones de manera normal, como en éste caso.

Chécate aquí 3 técnicas para referenciar correctamente los componentes:

https://youtu.be/hooHODgu6aM

Saludos!